# Filter ICollectionView top ten (or any top N)

Tags: c#, binding, icollectionview

I have an ObservableCollection of Value object called Values.
Value object has name, percentage and size properties.
Percentages are calculated among all values.

Then, i have a chart control binded to an IcollectionView created from the Values sorted by percentage.

```
var IValues = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = Dmodel.Values }.View;
Ivalues.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Percentage", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

I can apply a filter based on name, size, percentage... whatever.

```
IValues.Filter = o => 
{ 
    Value v = o as Value; 
    return v.Name.Contains(SearchedText); 
}
```

But, how can i filter the first N values of the IcollectionView?
I know how i can do it in the ObservableCollection with a simple:

```
Values = Values.OrderByDescending(x => x.Percentage).Take(10);
```

But i prefer to maintain the original data source untouched because i'm using a user control binding the ICollectionView and all the filtering logic is in the control code behind.

Thanks!

Comment: `But i prefer to maintain the original data source untouched` so don't overwrite `Values`?

Comment: I mean only pass the ICollectionView to the user control. But yes, i don't need to change any value, only read.

Answer (score 0):

Btw...

```
int count = 0;
int max = 50;
IValues.Filter += o => ++count <= max;
```

Will filter the first 50 (max) objects in IValues...